# How to binding xml to datagrid combobox

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I have a wpf project which used to binding xml to datagrid like follows:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgCommunication" ItemsSource="{Binding CommunicationsView}" FontSize="14" CanUserResizeColumns="False" BorderThickness="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10,10,10,15" Background="White">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParamName" Binding="{Binding ParamName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="ParamValue" Binding="{Binding ParamValues, Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="DefaultValue" Binding="{Binding DefaultValue}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="MaxValue" Binding="{Binding MaxValue}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="MinValue" Binding="{Binding MinValue}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And the xml file:

```
<NewDataSet>
   <Communications>
      <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
      <ParamName>BaudRate</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>19200</ParamValue>
      <DefaultValue>19200</DefaultValue>
      <MaxValue></MaxValue>
      <MinValue></MinValue>
   </Communications>
   <Communications>
      <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
      <ParamName>Parity</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>None</ParamValue>
      <DefaultValue>None</DefaultValue>
      <MaxValue></MaxValue>
      <MinValue></MinValue>
   </Communications>
   <Communications>
      <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
      <ParamName>StopBit</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>1</ParamValue>
      <DefaultValue>1</DefaultValue>
      <MaxValue></MaxValue>
      <MinValue></MinValue>
   </Communications>
   <Communications>
      <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
      <ParamName>DataBit</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>8</ParamValue>
      <DefaultValue>8</DefaultValue>
      <MaxValue></MaxValue>
      <MinValue></MinValue>
   </Communications>
   <Communications>
      <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
      <ParamName>SlaveAddress</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>1</ParamValue>
      <DefaultValue>1</DefaultValue>
      <MaxValue>247</MaxValue>
      <MinValue>1</MinValue>
   </Communications>
   <Communications>
      <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
      <ParamName>IP_Address</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>192.168.0.1</ParamValue>
      <DefaultValue>192.168.0.1</DefaultValue>
      <MaxValue></MaxValue>
      <MinValue></MinValue>
   </Communications>
   <Communications>
      <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
      <ParamName>IP_Port</ParamName>
      <ParamValue>502</ParamValue>
      <DefaultValue>502</DefaultValue>
      <MaxValue></MaxValue>
      <MinValue></MinValue>
   </Communications>
</NewDataSet>
```

This works fine. But now I have to change some of the `DataGridTextColumn` into `ComboBox`, taking `BaudRate` as an example, I may change the xml to:

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Communications>
        <ModelNumber>0x01</ModelNumber>
        <ParamName>BaudRate</ParamName>
        <ParamValues>
            <ParamValue>9600</ParamValue>
            <ParamValue>19200</ParamValue>
            <ParamValue>115200</ParamValue>
        </ParamValues>
        <DefaultValue>502</DefaultValue>
        <MaxValue></MaxValue>
        <MinValue></MinValue>
    </Communications>
</NewDataSet>
```

How should I do to make this happen?Thanks in advance!

Comment: See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7307/ComboBox-in-a-DataGrid Article includes all source code.  The article itself is just an explanation summary of the included source.

Comment: It's about winform, my project is WPF

Comment: The article started with : I needed a ComboBox in my DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you save the ParamValues as an List and using [DataGridComboBoxColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)

By using the MVVM-Model the XML-Docuemnt will be the Database and you have to built an model with an logik that will buitl the Objects. 
The Viewmodel will use the Modeldata and you can use an binding to the ParamValues if im supposed to be right.

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Values" ItemsSource="{Binding ParamValues, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SelectedParamValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```